# Is top-fermenting yeast more prone to building undesired byproducts during bottle fermentation than bottom-fermenting yeast?

Tags: bottle-conditioning, storage

Recently I finished my 6th batch of beer, the first top-fermenting one (wheat beer). The yeast is from a commercial brewery nearby, so I don't know its exact type. Usually my bottle fermentation takes place at cellar or even room temperatures and I put the bottles in the fridge a couple of days before drinking. For bottom-fermenting yeast this worked nicely so far.

**The bottle fermentation and storage of the new batch:**

Half of the batch (A): 4 weeks at room temperature

Half of the batch (B): one week at room temperature, 3 weeks in the fridge

Half B tastes really good, Half A shows a distinct sour overtone. Is top-fermenting yeast more prone to building undesired byproducts during bottle fermentation than bottom-fermenting yeast? Or could the summer temperatures be the reason? (Cellar: 10°C in the winter, 15°C in the summer, Room: 18°C in the winter, 23°C in the summer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have sour overtones, then you likely have either an acetobacter, pedio, lacto or a wild yeast contamination. And, having been at a warmer temperature for longer will have allowed this biological contamination more opportunity to generate sour off flavours to a level above the taste threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Not during bottle conditioning. Both ale and lager strains will behave the same and produce no esters.....

Unless there was oxygen contaminate then the yeast may try a growth phase again producing esters. In this scenario lager strain will produce more esters at warmer temps,than an ale strain will.

As already answered by Mr_road. A sour taste would be from a wild yeast or bacteria contaminate.